# Start index numbering at 1 (not 0) with $key

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've got a wordpress shortcode, giving me an array of ids to build a list of links. Everything's fine so far. But now I'd like to number these links, so I use $key to output the index. Unfortunately numbering (within the span tag) starts with zero (0) and I can't figure a way to add + 1 to $key :(

```
function wp_ytlinks($atts){

extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'id' => 1 ), $atts));
echo '<div class="videonav">';
$value = explode(',', $id);
$index = 0;
foreach ($value as $key=>$att_id)
{

echo '<a class="yt-vid" id="yt-load" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' .
$att_id . '?rel=0" target="screen"><span>' . $key . '</span></a>';
}    
};
add_shortcode('ytlinks', 'wp_ytlinks');
```

The Shortcode looks like this: [ytlinks id="J0Np2hn84Tc,cVHGLdZQgEw"]

Can s.o. please help?

Comment: `...<span>' . ($key + 1) . '</span>...` ?!

Comment: Thank you. Found a similar solution seconds before, yours is even shorter... Thanks for taking the time to answer such a question, really appreciate it :) FYI I never learned coding... I just alter code I find here and there. So...

Answer (score 0):

OKay, I don't know, after an hour of stupid back and forth I tried something REALLY easy and it worked...

```
foreach ($value as $key=>$att_id) {    
    $nums = $key + 1;
...
```

Why do I have to post a question here to find such an easy solution?! Sorry guys...